# Automatically send RSS feed to iTunes using Powerpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, rss, itunes, podcast

Can I automatically send RSS feed of Wordpress Podcast to iTunes using Powerpress?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but "send" is not the correct term.

Here's a quick explanation of how podcasting works:

An XML page on your web site (e.g. example.com/feed/podcast/) maintains a list of your blog posts/podcast episodes. This unique URL is then used to submit to podcast directories including iTunes. iTunes and other directories will check this URL every so often (iTunes case it's every 4 hours) for updates and changes. If iTunes sees new content, it will make that new content appear on the iTunes podcast directory, typically within a few hours. This process is better described as "syndication".

WordPress provides RSS feeds for blogging automatically. What PowerPress does is give you a podcast only RSS feed, which is necessary to optimize the blog posts in the feed for only podcast consumption. In a perfect world you would use the blog feed (which mixes your blog posts and episodes) for your news subscribers, and use the podcast only feed for your podcast subscriptions.